# How can a user with no sentry permissions on a table can execute queries if he has access to the table files in HDFS?

Tags: hadoop, hive, cloudera, sentry

As per https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/sg_sentry_service_config.html,

> HiveServer2 impersonation lets users execute queries and access HDFS files as the connected user rather than as the super user. **Access policies are applied at the file level using the HDFS permissions specified in ACLs (access control lists)**. Enabling HiveServer2 impersonation bypasses Sentry from the end-to-end authorization process. Specifically, although Sentry enforces access control policies on tables and views within the Hive warehouse, it does not control access to the HDFS files that underlie the tables. **This means that users without Sentry permissions to tables in the warehouse may nonetheless be able to bypass Sentry authorization checks and execute jobs and queries against tables in the warehouse as long as they have permissions on the HDFS files supporting the table.**

Access policies are applied at the file level using the HDFS permissions specified in ACLs (access control lists) -> I didn't understand this.
My undestanding is that, whenever a user runs a query, authorization will be done by the sentry plugin(binding) in the data engine with the help of sentry server to validate whether the user has access(select, insert) to the resources(db, table) he is trying to query. In this case, if the user doesn't have access to the resource, then it should fail here, how can the query be successful when he has access to the files corresponding to a table in HDFS and doesn't have sentry permissions on the table? What am I missing here?

Answer (score 0):

I feel like you didn't see "*users without Sentry permissions to tables in the warehouse*" part.

Sure, Sentry is used, but not all users are automatically given permissions, therefore it falls back to the ACLs applied at the HDFS level given by chown/chmod/setfacl functions. You need to explicitly add a "deny all" rule to say no one can access the Hive databases unless otherwise set

This can simply be bypassed as well by reading the raw HDFS location of the tables using Spark or Pig, and not using Hive. That's what it's really saying.

Also, not all Hadoop clusters use Sentry for authorized access

Comment: I agree your point. I have another doubt. If the hive warehouse directory in HDFS is owned by hive user and group, how can impala or hue apply the same authorization as of hive? Should impala and hue users be given permission to be impersonated by hive?

Comment: As the page says, "as long as they have permissions on the HDFS files", then uses can query. I don't know the impersonation configurations of Impala, but for Hue, by default, there is only a single user account, and you need to explicitly configure impersonation.